# Iterating through each column in my SQL table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, foreach

I have a SQL table with about 50 columns.  I want to be able to iterate through each one similar to a `foreach` loop.  When I iterate through each column, I want to check to see if there's a single double quote appended at the end, and if so, remove it.

I have this solution built out but I explicitly define the column names, see below:

```
select BrandName = 
   (CASE
        WHEN (BrandName like '%"') THEN LEFT(BrandName, LEN(BrandName) - 1)
        ELSE BrandName
    END),
    emailSubject = 
   (CASE
        WHEN (emailSubject like '%"') THEN LEFT(emailSubject , LEN(emailSubject ) - 1)
        ELSE emailSubject 
    END),
    -- and so on...
    from tableName
```

This works fine, but introduces some possibility of error.  So, this is why I want to do something like (pseudocode):

```
foreach column c in table
    if (c.EndsWith('"'))
        c.RemoveEndCharacter()
```

Is this possible, and if so can you provide some examples on how I might implement such a solution in T-SQL?

Thanks!

Comment: You can generate a SQL script based on [`sys.columns`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/en-en/library/ms176106.aspx).  However this looks like it'd be much easier client side, in C# or Python or a similar language.

Comment: You can iterate in sql, but usually you do not need to. Unlike other languages where you need to explicitly run through arrays, sql is structured around table data. Try to change how you are thinking about this problem because sql already evaluates each row of data to see if it fits your criteria. An update will work just fine for this situation. Let sql do the work for you, it is really good at these types of problems.

Comment: Is it OK to use .NET?

Answer (score 3):

You can generate tsql statements to update your table with the code below.  Execute the statement, then copy/paste the output into a new query window and run.  Alternatively, you could use the query below for a cursor and execute the output on each iteration.

```
SELECT 'UPDATE [' + c.TABLE_SCHEMA + '].[' + c.TABLE_NAME + '] SET [' + c.COLUMN_NAME + '] = LEFT([' + c.COLUMN_NAME + '], LEN([' + c.COLUMN_NAME + ']) - 1) WHERE [' + c.COLUMN_NAME + '] LIKE ''%"'''
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS c
JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES t
    ON t.TABLE_SCHEMA = c.TABLE_SCHEMA
    AND t.TABLE_NAME = c.TABLE_NAME

--For simple demo purposes, assume tables only.
WHERE t.TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE'

--Did I miss any data types?
AND c.DATA_TYPE IN ('NVARCHAR', 'VARCHAR', 'NCHAR', 'CHAR')

--Replace values with your corresponding schema/table name.
AND c.TABLE_SCHEMA = 'dbo'
AND c.TABLE_NAME = 'YourTableName'

ORDER BY c.TABLE_SCHEMA, c.TABLE_NAME, c.ORDINAL_POSITION
```